# How to model fading channels in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, ofdm, fading-channel

I am asked to write a MATLAB program for the simulation of the end-to-end transmission of a JPG file through a fading channel by using OFDM technique for one of my courses' term project.

I wrote my code, that is working like a charm, through a AWGN channel. However, I have no clue about modelling fading channels with different parameters and send my JPG file through them.

Let's say all OFDM symbols are created and converted into serial data stream (as a vector) thus they are ready to be transmitted into the channel, for AWGN, I simply used a built-in function "ofdm_signal = awgn(ofdm_signal,10);". But how to add fading & shadowing effects on my ofdm signal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The systematic way is that constructing a Fading channel object https://fr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/rayleighchan.html then use the `filter` function https://fr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/filter.html